# About posting queries in stack bioinformatics

Tags: discussion

If I have posted a question in Biostars and have not obtained answers, can I use the same query for finding answers in Stack bioinformatics?

Comment: Go right ahead. Just make sure you've waited long enough (say 3-4 days excluding weekends) and link the biostars post in your post here. Similarly, edit your biostars post and add the link to the new StackExchange post there.

Comment: I may add that you should critically ask yourself why the question did not receive answers. Was it simply a very specific question and people with the required expertise were not around, or did it lack details, formatting or clarity. If the latter please consider adding all this before submitting a new question.

Answer (score 6):

As Ram mentioned in his comment, there's nothing strictly forbidding this. It is, however, best to give it a few days before reposting here and please do link to the post on biostars. The goal with all of this is to not duplicate effort across sites (so users finding the question here can easily check if it was already answered elsewhere). Community effort is finite and we'd like to ensure that it's spent efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

> This is a long comment and not an answer

@ATpoint points out that there is a reason why Qs go unanswered and I could not agree more. The 81% answer-rate is below the 90% stated in [Area51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/109245/bioinformatics). I looked at my followed tags (comp-biochem) to categorise them and there seems to rarely be a lack of technical know-how.

- comment suggestion or link to answer ([here](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/17504/python-script-to-simultaneously-generate-multiple-pdbqt-files-for-autodocktools), [here](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/16177/best-way-to-dock-subset-of-protein-pdb-and-definition-of-a-ligand), [here](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/15609/finding-annotated-counterpart-after-blastn-with-efetch-biopython), [here](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/15143/biopython-retrieve-sequence-records-from-pubmed-database), [here](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/15061/how-to-extract-clusters-from-a-phylogenetic-tree))
- file not found or badly formatted ([here](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/17482/foldx-positionscan-functions-only-works-for-certain-position-inputs), [here](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/ligplot-how-to-define-path-in-ubuntu))
- impossible task ([here](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/16417/python-script-to-calculate-properties-of-amino-acids-and-storing-them-in-matrix), [here](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/16180/3d-model-of-a-protein-via-nucleotide-sequence), [here](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/15821/convert-smp-from-cdd-into-hmm-file))
- repost ([here](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/16180/3d-model-of-a-protein-via-nucleotide-sequence))
- user was doing SARS-CoV-2 drug repurposing ([here](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/16132/why-ace2-is-not-included-in-sars-cov-2-ppin-map))
- user has already best solution ([here](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/15204/regularly-extract-models-from-multimodel-pdb-file))
- beyond my expertise ([here](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/15135/java-protein-comparison-visualisation) —java, [here](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/15127/generate-multiple-output-file-based-on-editing-operations-done-on-pdb-input-file) —R)

Okay, this may be biased as advanced questions get asked in the ccp4 bulletin-board (ccp4bb), and in certain tools have their own discussion forum, such as [Rosetta commons](https://www.rosettacommons.org/forum).